# Python - Variation on [k] * n for list generation

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Given a list of elements `[1,27,10,...]` I need to generate a list of `n` repetitions of each element, as in [`1, 1, ..., 1, 27, 27, ..., 27, 10, ..., 10]`

What is the most elegant, most pythonic and fastest way of doing this?

**Answer**

`numpy` is the fastest and most concise solution.

`np.repeat(my_list, n)` looks very pythonic (credit to B.M.), while flattening a numpy array seems marginally faster.

Also have a look at the `numba` alternative below in B.M.'s post

**More detail**

I tested 3 approaches: i) double looping, ii) single looping with an indexing function and iii) flattening a numpy array. *(edit: 4th approach by Mike using `extend`, 5th approach with `np.repeat` by B.M., 6th approach comprehension by gsb-eng, 7th approach itertools)*

Surprisingly, I find that flattening an array is **by far** the fastest method on my machine in python 2.7. However, on some machines and in Python 3 you might want to test itertools and comprehensions. You can copy/paste the Python 2 code below for a quick check, the sorted `timeit` results are:

```
Flattened array: 8.8ms
Numpy Repeat: 10.87ms
Extend List: 14.37ms
Itertools Repeat: 14.91ms
Itertools  Chain Comprehension: 18.72ms
Itertools Chain: 18.73ms
Double Loop : 58.4ms
Single Loop + index by division: 251.29ms
Double Loop + comprehension: 255.76ms
```

And this is the code that generates the result:

```
import numpy as np

import timeit

n = 100

my_list = range(10)
n_elements = len(my_list)

# === Double Loop =============================================================
def double_loop():
    my_long_list = []

    for list_element in my_list:
        my_long_list += [list_element] * n

    return my_long_list

# === Double Loop with Comprehension =========================================================    
def double_loop_comp():

    # List comprehension
    return [i for i in my_list for j in xrange(n)]   

# === Single Loop with Indexing Function ======================================
def one_loop_with_indexing():
    my_long_list = []

    for i in range(n*n_elements):
        my_long_list.append(my_list[i // n]) 


    return my_long_list

# === Flattened Array =========================================================
def flattened_array():
    my_array = np.zeros([n_elements, n])

    for i in range(n_elements):
        my_array[i,:] = my_list[i]

    return my_array.flatten()

# === Extend List =========================================================
def extend_list():
    my_long_list = []
    for list_element in my_list:
        my_long_list.extend([list_element] * n)
    return my_long_list

# === Numpy Repeat =========================================================
def numpy_repeat():
    return np.repeat(my_list, n)

# === Itertools Repeat ========================================================
def iter_repeat():
    my_long_list = []
    for x in my_list:
        my_long_list.extend( itertools.repeat(x,n) )
    return my_long_list

# === Itertools Chain =========================================================
def iter_chain():
    return list( itertools.chain.from_iterable( itertools.repeat(x,n) for x in my_list ) )

# === Itertools Chain Comp ====================================================
def iter_chain_comp():
    return list( itertools.chain.from_iterable( [itertools.repeat(x,n) for x in my_list] ) )



time_double_loop = timeit.timeit(double_loop, number=1000)
time_double_loop_comp = timeit.timeit(double_loop_comp, number=1000)
time_single_loop = timeit.timeit(one_loop_with_indexing, number=1000)
time_flattened_array = timeit.timeit(flattened_array, number=1000)
time_extend_list = timeit.timeit(extend_list, number=1000)
time_np_repeat = timeit.timeit(numpy_repeat, number=1000)
time_it_repeat = timeit.timeit(iter_repeat, number=1000)
time_it_chain = timeit.timeit(iter_chain, number=1000)
time_it_chain_comp = timeit.timeit(iter_chain_comp, number=1000)

print 'Double Loop : ' + str(round(time_double_loop*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Double Loop + comprehension: ' + str(round(time_double_loop_comp*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Single Loop + index by division: ' + str(round(time_single_loop*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Flattened array: ' + str(round(time_flattened_array*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Extend List: ' + str(round(time_extend_list*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Numpy Repeat: ' + str(round(time_np_repeat*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Itertools Repeat: ' + str(round(time_it_repeat*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Itertools Chain: ' + str(round(time_it_chain*1000,2))+'ms'
print 'Itertools  Chain Comprehension: ' + str(round(time_it_chain_comp*1000,2))+'ms'
```

Comment: `flattened_array` is faster probably  because you are using `numpy` array

Comment: numpy is for efficiency, so no surprise. There is a numpy function to do that directly : `np.repeat(my_list,n)`

Comment: For me the *double loop* is the fastest. And for your integer division use `//` instead.

Comment: The comprehension is still wrong. Change `xrange(n_elements)` into `xrange(n)` and time again.

Comment: Ah you're right, now it is much slower. Editing again. Thanks for spotting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fast category, with `a=np.array(my_list)` (100 elements in tests):

Readable :

```
In [12]: %timeit np.repeat(a,100)
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.4 µs per loop
```

Tricky :

```
In [13]: %timeit np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,(100,100),(a.itemsize,0)).ravel()
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 µs per loop
```

Just in time compillation with numba (after `conda install numba`)

```
from numba import jit

@jit 
def numbarep(a,n):
    res=np.empty(a.size*n,dtype=a.dtype)
    offset=0
    for e in a:
        for k in range(offset,offset+n):
            res[k]=e
        offset+=n
    return res


In [14]: %timeit numbarep(a,100)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: No docs available : some good examples of `as_strided` usage here : http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides

Answer (score 3):

I've replaced the `flatten array` with native `list comprehension`....

```
[i for i in my_list for j in xrange(n)]
```

This one is more `pythonic` way of solution for this situation...

Below is the `timeit` results for the same..

```
Double Loop :0.0249750614166
Single Loop + indexing function: 0.198489904404
List comprehension: 0.00534200668335
```

Below is the full code after adding `list comprehension` entry in your code.

```
import timeit

n = 100

my_list = range(10)
n_elements = len(my_list)

# === Double Loop =============================================================
def double_loop():
    my_long_list = []

    for list_element in my_list:
        my_long_list += [list_element] * n

    return my_long_list

def double_loop_comp():

    # List comprehension
    return [i for i in my_list for j in xrange(n)]

# === Single Loop with Indexing Function ======================================
def one_loop_with_indexing():
    my_long_list = []

    for i in range(n*n_elements):
        my_long_list.append(my_list[i / n])  # !! This would not work if you use "from __future__ import division"


    return my_long_list


time_double_loop = timeit.timeit(double_loop, number=1000)
time_single_loop = timeit.timeit(one_loop_with_indexing, number=1000)
time_double_loop_comp = timeit.timeit(double_loop_comp, number=1000)

print 'Double Loop :' + str(time_double_loop)
print 'Single Loop + indexing function: ' + str(time_single_loop)
print 'List comprehension: ' + str(time_double_loop_comp)
```

Comment: Thanks, added in the original post. np still seems faster on my machine, though agree native comprehension is more Pythonic

Comment: But it does not give the same result `assert double_loop_comp() == double_loop()`  --> ` AssertionError

Comment: @MikeMüller I was trying to give `pythonic` solution, obviously adding `numpy` is not a `pythonic` solution for this, correct?

Comment: @Pythonic: I don't know but in my machine `comprehension` is the winner..        `Double Loop :0.0179278850555
Double Loop + comprehension :0.0077600479126
Single Loop + index by division: 0.174581050873
Flattened array: 0.0127079486847
Extend List: 0.0113019943237
Numpy Repeat: 0.0116000175476`

Comment: @Pythonic BTW, you must be checking this in `python 2.x`, correct?

Comment: But sadly it's not using the right count. It's using `n_elements` (10) instead of `n` (100)

Comment: Yes using python 2.7. Edited to account for the different results on your machine. thanks

Comment: @Pythonic Yeah got it :), but still `numpy` is not a `pythonic` way I guess.

Comment: Well that opens a long discussion :) I guess "pythonic" for me means short, elegant and with a "natural-language" feel. It does not have to be native, and furthermore numpy is so rooted in python. But this might become a long discussion... :)

Comment: You need  to update your timing after your change to `xrange(n)` in the comprehension.

Comment: @MikeMüller Sure , I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extend()`:

```
def extend_list():
    my_long_list = []
    for list_element in my_list:
        my_long_list.extend([list_element] * n)
    return my_long_list
```

It is faster on my machine:

```
Double Loop :0.0226180553436
Single Loop + indexing function: 0.300093889236
Flattened array: 0.0395331382751
Extend List: 0.0189819335938
```

List comprehension with right results:

```
def double_loop_comp():
    return [i for i in my_list for j in xrange(n)]
```

The list comprehension is slower:

```
Double Loop :0.016893863678
Single Loop + indexing function: 0.300258874893
Flattened array: 0.0327677726746
Extend List: 0.0180258750916
Comp: 0.0602869987488
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, will edit the post, on my machine the flattened_array seems still faster by 2x

Answer (score 1):

you can also use itertools to get the list, also in my machine is the fastest of all

```
import itertools as it
n = 100
my_list = range(10)
n_elements = len(my_list)

def iter_repeat():
    my_long_list = []
    for x in my_list:
        my_long_list.extend( it.repeat(x,n) )
    return my_long_list

def iter_chain():
    return list( it.chain.from_iterable( it.repeat(x,n) for x in my_list ) )

def iter_chain_comp():
    return list( it.chain.from_iterable( [it.repeat(x,n) for x in my_list] ) )
```

using your script to test it I get this times in python3

```
Double Loop :                     0.015303148491881732
Double Loop + comprehension :     0.04365179467151968
Single Loop + index by division:  0.3784320416645417
Extend List:                      0.01603116899830609
Flattened array:                  0.018885064147608488
Numpy Repeat:                     0.0254420405658366
Itertools repeat extend:          0.015163157712790254
Itertools chain repeat:           0.025397544719181653
Itertools chain repeat comp:      0.025096342064901633

order
0.015163157712790254 time_iter_repeat
0.015303148491881732 time_double_loop
0.01603116899830609 time_extend_list
0.018885064147608488 time_flattened_array
0.025096342064901633 time_iter_chain_comp
0.025397544719181653 time_iter_chain
0.0254420405658366 time_np_repeat
0.04365179467151968 time_double_loop_comp
0.3784320416645417 time_single_loop
```

and in python 2 I get

```
Double Loop :                     0.0188628162243
Double Loop + comprehension :     0.069114371782
Single Loop + index by division:  0.239681327592
Extend List:                      0.0197920948679
Itertools repeat extend:          0.0275025405417
Itertools chain repeat:           0.0315609040324
Itertools chain repeat comp:      0.0317361492131

order
0.0188628162243 time_double_loop
0.0197920948679 time_extend_list
0.0275025405417 time_iter_repeat
0.0315609040324 time_iter_chain
0.0317361492131 time_iter_chain_comp
0.069114371782 time_double_loop_comp
0.239681327592 time_single_loop
```

(I don't have numpy in python2 and is a pain to install it so I don't do that test)

Comment: Added itertools above, flattening still fastest on my machine. Could be a python 2 vs 3 thing?

Comment: yeah, it could be many thing like python 2 vs 3 because in my machine the double loop win in 2 (without numpy) but iter_repeat win in 3 (with numpy), the machine and the OS can also play a role, my is a dual core of 3GHz with Windons

Answer (score 0):

If the result only must be iterable but doesn't have to be a list, you can 'cheat' by only creating a generator:

```
import itertools as it

def make_generator():
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(elem, n) for elem in my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do need a list (practically, it is an indexer for work done in pandas)